# Spring batch jobOperator - how are multiple concurrent instances of a job from the same XML file controlled?

Tags: spring-batch

When we run multiple concurrent jobs with different parameters, how can we control (stop, restart) the appropriate jobs?  Our internal code provides the jobExecution object, but under the covers The jobOperator uses the job name to get the job instance.

In our case all of the jobs are from "do-stuff.xml" (okay, it's sanitized and not very original).  After looking at the spring-batch source code, our concern is that if there is more then one job running and we stop a job it will take the most recently submitted job and stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JobOperator` will allow you to fetch all running executions of the job using `getRunningExecutions(String jobName)`. You should be able to iterate over that list to find the one you want. Then, just call `stop(long executionId)` on the one you want.

Alternatively, we've also implemented listeners (both at step and chunk level) to check an outage status table. When we want to implement a system-wide outage, we add the outage there and have our listener throw an exception to bring our jobs down. once the outage is lifted, all "failed" executions may be restarted.

Comment: Thank you!  Once we have a chance to prove this out I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: So which option did you go with?

Comment: We implemented the JobOperator.getRunningExecutions() mechanism. Since outages are scheduled in quartz, this allows us to stop/restart the job without altering the jobs themselves.